# Is there any way to control styling options in R Markdown when generating PDF?

Tags: html, css, r, pdf, rstudio

I am using R Markdown in RStudio to generate some documentation.

My output looks good when I try the option of "Knit HTML". I am able to control styling options and apply CSS Files explicitly.

However when I try to "Knit PDF" (I had to install pdf-tex before being able to do that) I can't change the default styling method. Also, the tables go out of margins. Is there any method to provide or use CSS Files or themes before creating PDF in RStudio using RMarkdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the R Markdown [Reference Guide](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf), there is no in-built solution to style a document with **CSS** or **theme** when knitting a PDF.

See screenshot below:

[image]